# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 won't install (see error log)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
[01/18/10,18:49:13] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Beta 2 - ENU: [2] Failed to fetch setup file in CGRootComponent::PreInstall(), cancelled
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467260.
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallPhase() - Call to Pre/Install/Post for InstallComponents failed
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallPhaseAndCheckResults() - RunInstallPhase() returned a NULL piActionResults
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallFromList() - RunInstallPhaseAndCheckResults failed [2]
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] ISetupManager::RunInstallLists(IP_PREINSTALL failed in ISetupManager::RunInstallFromThread()
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] ISetupManager::RunInstallFromThread() failed in ISetupManager::RunInstall()
[01/18/10,18:49:13] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::Run() - Call to RunInstall() failed
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is out.  Why are you installing the beta?

Comment: If you can't afford the full version then there are the Express versions downloadable for free. Yes they have limitation, but might be OK for you.

Comment: Beta 2 expires on June 30th.  Don't waste your time trying to get it installed.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Beta 2 is now not supported and may even be set up so that it won't install or run. You should go out and buy the full version of Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Very true. Happened on my laptop a few days ago. Won't start properly.